# What does chmod 789 represent?

Tags: command-line, permissions

This was one of my exam questions, I wanted to know what does it represent?

The question was:

What is the equivalent of running chmod 789 a.txt?

- `chmod u=rw,g+w,o-x a.txt`
- `chmod a=rwx,u+s a.txt`
- `chmod u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx a.txt`
- other

Comment: [put in a little effort next time](https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/697/unix-advanced-octal-file-permissions-with-chmod/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

8 and 9 are not valid.   Unfortunately, your list of options does not clearly have a 'not valid' option.  Though, all you had to do was try this in unix to find your answer.